# How to check the status of checkbox in java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox

I have around 200 hundred checkboxes in a Java GUI. Now I want to have the list of all checkboxes that have been checked by the user.

I can do it in one way like this:

```
jCheckBox1.isSelected();
```

But I don't want to write this line for 200 checkboxes. Is there any way to do this through a for loop.

all the checkboxes have the name like jCheckBox1, jCheckBox2, jCheckBox3, jCheckBox4 ... jCheckBox200

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You really should have put these in an array or Collection so that you can just loop over them. eg.

```
List<JCheckBox> allCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>()
allCheckboxes.add(new JCheckBox());
```

etc.

If you have all these checkboxes declared as members then there's no excuse to just put them in a list instead.

In the meantime you could use a dodgy cast in a for loop (if all the checkboxes are on the same panel)

```
boolean allSelected = true;
for(Component component : myPanel.getComponents()) {
  if(component instanceof JCheckBox) {
    allSelected &= ((JCheckBox)component).isSelected();
  }
}
```

I'd recommend reading about Java arrays and collections before continuing

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, what should I say?

OK, You should starts by using array to hold all check boxes you have so you can loop through it.

In case that is too late, you may have a another choice by loop though all elements on that container (only work if all checkboxes are on the same container). Something like '`jPanel1.getComponents()`' and then loop them only see which is a Checkbox.

Anyway .. I think, you should put all those in an array and save yourself from a variable mess.

Comment: You answer is also an accepted answer but I can mark only one answer as accepted answer. Sorry for that but a lot of thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have your checkboxes in an array... you can do it in a loop.

```
JCheckBox[] myBoxes = new JCheckBox[200];

//Some creation stuff here

for (int i=0; i<myBoxes.length; ++i) {
   if (myBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
       //Do stuff!
   }
}
```

Comment: No. They are not in an array. Actually the GUI code is a generated code so I can't change that code.

Comment: Oh that's BRUTAL.  You can do this by reflection in a loop if you're really lazy... however an alternative is to make a method to handle the checkbox logic and just call handleCheckbox(checkbox1)... that way only the handleCheckbox method is written a bajillion times